# Setting alarm on monthly basis android

Tags: java, android, math, alarmmanager

I am developing an android app for setting alarm on daily, weekly, monthly basis. The first two are working fine by converting the give date and time into milliseonds. But when I am trying to do the same for monthly it doesn't work. There is totally different date format.

I am setting it as below,

Alarmtimefor30 has the given date in milliseconds.

```
  am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTimefor30, 30*1440*60000 , pi);
```

I am giving intervalMillis as 30*1440*60000 which results to 2592000000 i.e 30 days in milliseconds. When I try to print 30*1440*60000 it results to 1702967296. I am not sure what could be the problem.

Is there another way to set monthly alarm (to trigger on specific date and time every month)?

Please Help!Thanks!

Comment: Do you think your device is going to be on for full month ?

Comment: are you going to keep on your device for full month ? dont you think at any moment when there is no battery, it will be shut down and alarm values will start again.

Comment: True. What is the best way?

Comment: One of the best way would be store your Alarm Value when shutDown event is occured, so that next time when device boots it start alarm value from where it left :)

Comment: @Vigbyor aren't alarm settings preserved between reboots?

Comment: @DuncanACoulter, default alarm's value preserves in the Android system it self, but user defined alarm never saved once device is shut down.

Comment: @Vigbyor I didn't know that. Definitely something to watch out for.

Comment: @DuncanACoulter For Developer when a method is not there available then better to code your self :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, an integer literal in Java will be of type `int`, which is a 32-bit number.  When you multiply an `int` by an `int` the result is also an `int`, so your result is being truncated.  Obviously the argument to `setRepeating` is a `long`, but that doesn't mean the compiler will fix this for you - your multiplication will still be truncated.

The solution is to explicitly force the literals to be of type `long`, which is a 64-bit number:

```
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTimefor30, 30L*1440L*60000L , pi);
```