# android : setting alarm on monthly basis

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I am developing an android app for setting the alarm on monthly basis. I have given the below code for next month.

```
private int GetTotalDays(int  monthRecvd1) {

    int totalDays=getDaysInMonthInPresentYear(taskMonth1);
    myDays=(totalDays-taskdate1)+taskdate1;
            }

                private int getDaysInMonthInPresentYear(int taskMonth1) 
                {
                    int days=0;
                    alarmCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, Hrs);  
                    alarmCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Mins);
                    alarmCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                    alarmCalendar.set(Calendar.DATE, date);
                    alarmCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Month);
                    alarmCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                    Long alarmTime = alarmCalendar.getTimeInMillis();
                    calendar.set(year, Month, date);
                    days = calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                 }
```

This code works only for next month. and doesn't work on second next month. for example, if i set the alarm on april, it will set for may but not for june and so on.

Can anybody tell me what could be the solution for this.

Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `setRepeating(int type, long triggerAtMillis, long intervalMillis, PendingIntent operation)` method rather than just AlarmManager.set(). You can find more info on documentation.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Edit: It should like this

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(AndroidAlarmService.this, this);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(AndroidAlarmService.this, 0, serviceIntent, 0);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
long now = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
calendar.add(Calendar.DATE,calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.MONTH));
long repeat = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, now , repeat , pendingIntent);
}
```

Comment: iam using the same method.                                                 interval=(Long.valueOf(nxtmonth))*24L*60L*60L*1000L;  am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTimefor30, interval, pi);

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
        SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to explicitly force the literals to be of type long, which is a 64-bit number:

am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTimefor30, 30L*1440L*60000L , pi);

Source:

[Setting alarm on monthly basis android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17857920/setting-alarm-on-monthly-basis-android)